# What does "undoable" mean?

Tags: connotation, meaning

When something is undoable, does it mean that it has the ability to be reverted back to its previous state or does it mean that it's not feasible?

> I broke something on my computer and a fix is undoable. :(
>   I broke something on my computer but it's undoable. :)

Comment: Sounds very contrived. Use fix instead. I broke something but it is fixable. I broke something, and it is unfixable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both, actually. In the sense that something can be reverted to its prior state, the word is formed by joining *undo* and *-able*, literally something that is able to be undone. In the sense that something cannot be done, the word is formed by joining *un-* and *doable*, literally something that is not doable. While the two etymologies converge at *un-* + *do* + *-able*, the order in which the affixation occurs is the important thing.

Source: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undoable) and personal experience

Comment: This reminds me of _unpublished_.