# Pronunciation of "undoable"

Tags: pronunciation

As [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14580/what-does-undoable-mean) points out, there are two different meanings of *undoable*.

I can't find any phonetics how they are pronounced. I guess that the difference is barely audible. Or do you stress the word so that it is capable of being differentiated?

I found phonetics for undo and doable<sup>[(copied from OALD)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/)</sup>

- undo: `ʌnˈduː`
- doable: `ˈduːəbl`

It would be logical that both *undo-able* and *un-doable* are pronounced equal.

- `ʌnˈduː` has a trailed `əbl`
- `ˈduːəbl` has a precedent `ʌn`.

Both leads to: `ʌnˈduːəbl`.

But I conjecture this pronunciation to differentiate them:

- un-doable: `ʌnˈduːəbl`
- undo-able: `ˈʌnduːəbl`

Is there any audible difference in pronunciation? Perhaps are there also any difference between British and American English?

Comment: There is no difference in pronunciation. In both cases the stress would fall on the middle syllable.

Comment: "too localised" - who apart from OP would conjecture this difference in pronunciation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your pronunciation of 'doable' looks correct (for AmE)
- the phonemes you have for 'undo' look correct, but the stress pattern, though formally correct may not allow you to draw inferences about changes well. It is more a word with two stressed syllables (a 'spondee')
- adding on affixes is not independent in English. You have to take in to account the whole word to get it right.
- so the correct pronunciation is your first one `ʌnˈduːəbl`

As an aside, the schwa in English (or GenAmE, I can't speak for others) is always in an unstressed position, and the 'ʌ' is almost a schwa.